# How to limit port range in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, sysctl

I want to limit source port range in my ubuntu machine upto 20000 , that means no Application should be able to use port higher than that.I have this command in mind

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 20001:65535 --dport 20001:65535 -j DROP
```

But , wouldn't this drop all packets rather than limiting ? I need a configuration such that I can still browse the web , just not through port 20001 to 65535 . No incoming or outgoing through this ports.

Answer (score 3):

Edit `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` with:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

or any other editor of your choice and add or change:

```
# Allowed local port range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 20000
```

Restart your network.